# Error while connecting to cloudsql-mysql via go application

Tags: mysql, go, google-cloud-sql

I am connecting my go application to cloudsql-mysql through private IP. Below is my code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "sync"

    "cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn"
    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

const instanceURI = "%s:%s:%s"

func main(){
    instance := fmt.Sprintf(instanceURI, db.Project, db.GCRegion, db.Instance)
    d, err := cloudsqlconn.NewDialer(context.Background(), cloudsqlconn.WithOptions(cloudsqlconn.WithCredentialsJSON(db.ServiceAccount)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    mysql.RegisterDialContext("cloudsqlconn",
        func(ctx context.Context, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return d.Dial(ctx, instance, cloudsqlconn.WithPrivateIP())
        })
    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@cloudsqlconn(%s)/%s?parseTime=true",
        db.User, db.Password, instance, db.DbName)
    dbPool, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbURI)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        
    }
    err = dbPool.PingContext(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Errors %s pinging DB", err)
    }

}
```

I am getting the below error.

`unexpect resp from server for caching_sha2_password perform full authentication`

Can someone please help with reason for the error.

I followed the below document
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-connectors

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're connected to your database, but the authorization is failing ([source](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/master/auth.go#L379)).

Have you tried connecting directly with the same username and password?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect with the same username and password through CLI. But not through code

Comment: the go application is hosted on GKE and I am able to connect to mysql through CLI from the same cluster using the same username and password. But it gives this error when I am trying to connect through my application.